# To get the content of first two lines from UITextView without using next line object

Tags: iphone

I need to get the two lines of content from uitextview, but without using nextline.. I entered the text continuously on uitextview without press enter the line goes to second line automatically. when I print those text it is showing single line. But the content is two or more than two lines. How I can get that content from UITextView.

Comment: check how many character in one line

Answer (score 0):

You need to count (roughly) number of characters that can be entered in a single line.

Then using modulo and division you can find number of lines the text consumed.